# unable access my PC local host in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm new to android and I want to access my PC local host in android emulator I tried using 10.0.2.2  but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add port number in your localhost ip like **your_machine_ip_address:port_number**

try below. May it will help you:

Find console port number for the target emulator instance. Lets say it is 5554(which is written over emulator)

Then execute below command on command prompt:
**telnet localhost 5554**

after that execute :

**redir add tcp:8080:80**

here 8080 will be local port and 80 will be your server port.

and after finishing all this you can use localhost like below: 
**your_machine_ip_address:80**

you can find more detail on :

[developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html)

Answer (score 0):

Within your emulator, "localhost" refers to the emulator device itself.  If you want to reference your local PC, you must use its IP address or its fully-qualified name (e.g. mypc.foo.com).